# How to reduce the number if calls to np.sum() for below code?(test rules dictate only 2 calls can be made)

Tags: python, numpy

first_half_second_half gets a 2d array of shape (n,2*m) as a parameter. The output from the function should be a matrix with those rows from the input that have the sum of the first m elements larger than the sum of the last m elements on the row

This solution works but the number  of calls to np.sum() depends on test size data.Is there any possible way to achieve this using only two np.sum() calls

```
def first_half_second_half(a):
    len=int(a.shape[1]/2)
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        if np.sum(a[i,:len])>np.sum(a[i,len:]):
            arr.append(a[i,:])
    return np.array(arr)

a = np.array([[1, 3, 4, 2],
              [2, 2, 1, 2]])
first_half_second_half(a)

**array([[2, 2, 1, 2]])**
```

For random test data:
20 != 2 : Expected exactly two calls to function np.sum!

Comment: np.sum has Time complexity of O(n), so in you case it does not matter if it is one call (O(n)) or two calls (O(n/2) + O(n/2) = O(n)).

Comment: SO what is your problem?

Comment: Yes, I understand but if shape of a is (5,6) then ten np.sum() calls are made.Is there any way to achieve this using exactly two np.sum() calls

Comment: You are traversing your array linearly (you are visiting each cell one time), so there is nothing to optimize. Unless you are using these calculation in somewhere else then you may use 2D cumulative sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this

```py
m = a.shape[1]//2 # assuming it has even number of columns
sum1 = np.sum(a[:,:m], axis=1) #sum first half
sum2=np.sum(a[:,m:], axis=1) #sum second half
a[sum1>sum2] # get rows whose 1st half sum is greater
```